# Mongo Db unwind + group

Tags: mongodb

i have tried the sequent query:

```
db.getCollection("chatrooms").aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $lookup: // Equality Match

          {
          from: 'userProfiles',
          localField: 'participants.0.userId',
          foreignField: 'userId',
          as: 'utente'
        }


        // Uncorrelated Subqueries
        // (supported as of MongoDB 3.6)
        // {
        //    from: "<collection to join>",
        //    let: { <var_1>: <expression>, …, <var_n>: <expression> },
        //    pipeline: [ <pipeline to execute on the collection to join> ],
        //    as: "<output array field>"
        // }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$utente",

        }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
        $addFields: {
          "azienda": "$utente.businessName",
        }
    },

    // Stage 4
    {
        $group: {
               _id : null,
               count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
    },
],
```

in addfields stage i have for result 2 document, but in the group stage i have always 0 results, someone have an idea of why i have no results in last stage, (in previous there is results)

Comment: can you post both collections!!

Comment: this is the result of 3 stage :

Comment: _id:60ab7f49d9f27d965c41476e
isDistinct:false
participants:Array
createdAt:2021-05-24T10:26:17.587+00:00
updatedAt:2021-05-24T10:26:17.587+00:00
__v:0
utente:Object
azienda:"RUNE&LAB"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the _Stage 4_ of your pipeline; it should return 1 document with count. Instead of `$group` + `$sum` to count, you can also use `$count` stage (with the same result). Valid with your MongoDB v3.6.